# Is there a way to make this better?

Tags: algorithm

So was experimenting in making a rotating ring puzzle like the one to get into the mechanical age in Myst. I came up with a solution that will rotate the rings and when the button is released it brings then smoothly back to a set position. Their is obviously a better way to do this but I for some reason can see it.

The CheckRotation function checks were the ring is and give the angle that it should be at to the ResetRotator function and sets face (a public int) to the face that is currently facing the player. The isResettingOne variable stops the user from being able to bush the button that causes the rotation whilst the ring is resetting.

```
void CheckRotation()
{
    StopCoroutine(ResetRotator(lastPassed));

    yRotation = gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y;

    if (yRotation >= 337.5 && yRotation < 359.9 || yRotation >= 0 && yRotation < 22.5)//0
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(0));
        lastPassed = 0;
    }
    else if (yRotation >= 22.5 && yRotation < 67.5)//45
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(45));
        lastPassed = 45;
    }
    else if (yRotation >= 67.5 && yRotation < 112.5)//90
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(90));
        lastPassed = 90;
    }
    else if (yRotation >= 112.5 && yRotation < 157.5)//135
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(135));
        lastPassed = 135;
    }
    else if (yRotation >= 157.5 && yRotation < 202.5)//180
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(180));
        lastPassed = 180;
    }
    else if (yRotation >= 202.5 && yRotation < 247.5)//225
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(225));
        lastPassed = 225;
    }
    else if (yRotation >= 247.5 && yRotation < 292.5)//270
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(270));
        lastPassed = 270;
    }
    else if (yRotation >= 292.5 && yRotation < 337.5)//315
    {
        StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(315));
        lastPassed = 315;
    }
}

IEnumerator ResetRotator(int desiredRotation)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
    reset = (int)gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y;
    resettingOne = true;

    if(reset == desiredRotation)
    {
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
        resettingOne = false;
    }
    else if(desiredRotation == 0 && reset >= 0 && reset < 22.5)
    {
        face = 1;
        reset = reset - desiredRotation;
        reset = reset - 1;
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
        CheckRotation();
    }
    else if(desiredRotation == 0 && reset >= 337.5 && reset < 359.9)
    {
        face = 1;
        reset = reset + 1;
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
        CheckRotation();
    }
    else if (reset >= 22.5 && reset < 67.5)//45
    {
        face = 2;
        if(reset >= 22.5 && reset < 45)
        {
            reset = reset + 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
        if(reset > 45 && reset < 67.5)
        {
            reset = reset - 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
    }
    else if (reset >= 67.5 && reset < 112.5)//90
    {
        fcae = 3;
        if (reset >= 67.5 && reset < 90)
        {
            reset = reset + 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
        if (reset > 90 && reset < 112.5)
        {
            reset = reset - 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
    }
    else if (reset >= 112.5 && reset < 157.5)//135
    {
        face = 4;
        if (yRotation >= 112.5 && yRotation < 135)
        {
            reset = reset + 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
        if (reset > 135 && reset < 157.5)
        {
            reset = reset - 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
    }
    else if (reset >= 157.5 && reset < 202.5)//180
    {
        face = 5;
        if (reset >= 157.5 && reset < 180)
        {
            reset = reset + 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
        if (reset > 180 && reset < 202.5)
        {
            reset = reset - 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
    }
    else if (reset >= 202.5 && reset < 247.5)//225
    {
        face = 6;
        if (reset >= 202.5 && reset < 225)
        {
            reset = reset + 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
        if (reset > 225 && reset < 202.5)
        {
            reset = reset - 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
    }
    else if (reset >= 247.5 && reset < 292.5)//270
    {
        face = 7;
        if (reset >= 247.5 && reset < 270)
        {
            reset = reset + 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
        if (reset > 270 && reset < 292.5)
        {
            reset = reset - 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
    }
    else if (reset >= 292.5 && reset < 337.5)//315
    {
        face = 8;
        if (reset >= 292.5 && reset < 315)
        {
            reset = reset + 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
        if (reset > 315 && reset < 337.5)
        {
            reset = reset - 1;
            gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(reset, Vector3.up);
            CheckRotation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions about how to improve code can also be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell the purpose of your code is to always round to 45° increments. So you can use the function [Mathf.Round](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html). It always rounds to the nearest integer. When you want to round to the nearest multiply of 45, you need to divide the angle by 45, apply the rounding and then multiply it again:

```
float newAngle = Mathf.Round(yRotation / 45.0f) * 45.0f;
StartCoroutine(ResetRotator(newAngle)
lastPassed = newAngle;
```

The same technique can be applied in the ResetRotator method itself. The face can be calculated by dividing the angle and then using [Mathf.FloorToInt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) and whether you need to increment or decrement the `reset` variable (whatever it means) can be found out by comparing the original angle with the rounded one.